# Copy every 512 bytes and skip next 8 bytes from Input file to a Output file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have an input file which is always a multiple of 520 bytes . i,e

```
Input file 1- 1040 bytes
Input file 2- 5200 bytes
```

I need to copy every 512 bytes from input file and skip the next 8 bytes from input files to output file i.e

`Output file data = Copy first 512 bytes of input file - Skip 8 bytes - Copy second 512 bytes of input file- Skip 8 bytes --.`.

Therefore, my output file should always be multiple of 512 bytes

```
Input file 1- 1040 bytes        Output file 1 - 1024 bytes
Input file 2- 5200 bytes        Output file 2 - 5120 bytes
```

I need to do this in shell script, any help here please.

Comment: Processing binary data in a shell script is difficult. It might be easier to use other scripting languages or a C program.

Comment: I need to do this Shell script . I am sure there is a way we can with dd tool, but really stuck on how to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The right tool

[`bbe`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bbe) is "a `sed`-like editor for binary files". In Debian it's in a package named `bbe`. What you want can be done like this:

```
<"Input file 1" bbe -b :520 -e 'd 512 *' >"Output file 1"
```

`bbe` is the right tool. If you can use it then use it. The below script is in case you cannot use `bbe`.

---

#### Portable script

Not the fastest code but here it is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

useful=512
useless=8

while :; do
   dd bs=1 count="$useful" 2>/dev/null
   [ "$(dd bs=1 count="$useless" 2>/dev/null | wc -c)" -lt "$useless" ] && exit
done
```

Save the code as `my_filter`, then invoke:

```
<"Input file 1" ./my_filter >"Output file 1"
```

Notes:

- I think the code is portable.
- `bbe` is way faster (although with a file of 5200 bytes or less you probably won't notice the difference).
- It may seem `bs="$useful" count=1` should be better, but only if your `dd` supports `iflag=fullblock` (it may not) and you use it. Read [*What's the POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278443/108618)
- The code exits when the second `dd` reads less than it should. This way EOF is detected. For your files ("always a multiple of 520 bytes") the first `dd` will read less than it should before the second one does, but detecting this situation with the first `dd` in a portable way while still saving the output is not as straightforward as using `wc -c` with the second `dd` whose output should be discarded anyway.
- Because of how the script detects EOF, it won't discard a partial useful block if it ever happens (i.e. if EOF happens in the middle of it). For your files ("always a multiple of 520 bytes") this should never happen though. With arbitrary sizes it can happen. Note the provided `bbe` command generates the same output as the script even in these circumstances.
- To customize the script and use values other than 512 and 8, it's enough to modify the `useful=512` and `useless=8` lines.
- Because of how the script detects EOF, it will never exit if you set `useless=0` (this edge case is trivially solved by `cp "Input file 1" "Output file 1"`).
- `dd` supports `skip=`. Using it to skip `$useless` bytes seems quite elegant, but then detecting EOF gets complicated.
- You can easily modify the code to take `useful` and `useless` from positional parameters. `$1` expands to the value of the first positional parameter, `$2` expands to the value of the second. So instead of `useful=512` and `useless=8` you can use `useful="$1"` and `useless="$2"` respectively. Then instead of `./my_filter` you need to run `./my_filter 512 8`. This will allow you to pass arbitrary values at runtime.

Comment: Perfect answer..Thanks again !!.

Comment: Can we also input useful and useless as arguments to the command <"Input file 1" ./my_filter >"Output file 1" ??

Comment: @ivl See the last bullet point.